# Sending mail notification when ArgoCD sync failure

Tags: continuous-integration, argo-workflows, argocd

While deploying an application in K8, if argoCD sync failed, Any way to handle those by sending an email to user through kubernetes configurations

Comment: https://argocd-notifications.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 3):

you can use Argo Notifications for this, this is now baked into ArgoCD in the newest version.

It involves using annotations on the app, and setting the template in the notifications configmap. all documentation can be found here: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/notifications/